# How do i get userenv.log to log dates?

Tags: windows, log-files, logging

How do i get the userenv.log (C:\WINDOWS\Debug\UserMode\userenv.log) to log dates as well as times?

The current format is this

```
USERENV(2b4.498) 10:51:22:140 ProcessGPOs: Extension Microsoft Offline Files skipped because both deleted and changed GPO lists are empty.
USERENV(2b4.498) 10:51:22:140 ProcessGPOs: -----------------------
USERENV(2b4.498) 10:51:22:140 ProcessGPOs: Processing extension Software Installation
USERENV(2b4.498) 10:51:22:140 CompareGPOLists:  The lists are the same.
```

But since the log can roll over multiple days it would be very helpful to get dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a simple way to do this - others [have the same problem](http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid68_gci1294555,00.html).

How about a script that moves the contents of userenv.log to a new file at midnight? Would a separate log file for each day be any use to you?

Comment: Accepted this as viable answer even though it is not possible in my current environment. Thanks Adam

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing a reverese read of the file and counting down a date value.
The date gets decemented whenever the previous lines time is greater than the current line.

This is not an optimal solution, as there are a few bugs, but it is suitable for my purposes